# Can photons be created without an electric charge involved?

Tags: black-holes, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, neutrons, virtual-particles

It seems that in common ways how to produce light (electromagnetic waves, photons) must be involved particles with electric charge: accelerating electrons, spontaneous or stimulated emission, gamma rays from (charged) nuclei. Is it possible to create a photon *without* electric charge?

Two or three ways came to my mind:

1. annihilation of neutron and antineutron which would produce two photons
2. Hawking radiation of black holes (virtual pair of photons is created in vacuum just above the horizon and one of them is captured by the black hole)
3. rare mode of free neutron decay to proton, electron and electron antineutrino plus gamma ray, but in this case - according to Wikipedia - "gamma ray may be thought of as a sort of "internal bremsstrahlung" that arises as the emitted beta particle interacts with the charge of the proton in an electromagnetic way".

Answer (score 2):

Another example - neutron acceleration (say, in gravitational field), as neutrons have magnetic moment.

Comment: So magnetic moment is enough to create photons?

Comment: @LeosOndra: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_radiation#Magnetic_dipole_radiation

Comment: Why I'm not surprised? Since the neutron can be accelerated by photons and by this some momentum over goes to the neutron so during deceleration some photons have to be realized.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler: But I mentioned acceleration by gravitation field, not by photons.

Comment: Reading the Wikipedia article on Neutron magnetic moment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_magnetic_moment) I think that its magnetic moment arises from charged quarks inside, so we are again at electric charge, isn't it?

Comment: @LeosOndra: That is correct. I mentioned neutrons because you mentioned them in your question:-) If you need something "cleaner", consider neutrino-antineutrino annihilation (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0029558266902331)

Comment: akhmeteli The freefall in gravitational field is not an acceleration at all, the particles follow geodesic paths (and do not feel any acceleration).  -  Acceleration of neutrons by photons is a realistic scenario and from the fact of the momentum transfer follows a photon emission during deceleration.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field, a charge falling in a gravitational field still radiates with respect to an observer at rest. I guess the same is true for a magnetic moment. While I agree that "Acceleration of neutrons by photons is a realistic scenario", it does not make much sense in the context of the OP's question: why create a photon by acceleration of a neutron by photons? You already have photons, if you accelerate the neutron, using them, right?

Comment: While this is technically correct, the neutron's magnetic moment and mass are so small that, for non-relativistic (i.e. earth-scale or sun-scale) gravitational fields, any radiation would be of order nano-eV. For comparison, CMB photons are micro-eV.

Comment: @rob : I agree that this process is economically hopeless:-)

Answer (score 2):

There's something (not confirmed) called the [Hawking-Unruh Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect).  It's similar to Hawking radiation, but instead of a black hole, this effect involves an accelerating observer.

It's a strange sort of thing, since an observer at rest wouldn't see the black-body radiation, but the accelerating observer would.

One note: Neutrons only have a magnetic field because they are made of electrically charged quarks.  Fundamental particles with no electric charge also have no magnetic dipole.

Comment: So far it seems to me that Hawking or Unruh radiation are the only candidates for photon creation without electric charge.... But are they radiation of photons or particles?

Comment: @DavidElm Your final note is not quite correct.  For example, the Standard Model neutrino spends part of its time as an electron-$W$ loop, from which it acquires a small magnetic moment.

Comment: It looks like it's possible that neutrinos have a magnetic moment, but this doesn't seemed to have been verified.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Properties_and_reactions

Answer (score -1):

Neutrino and antineutrino annihilation results in 3 photons

Neutrino and antineutrino creates Z boson which decays to 3 photons.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that reaction?

Comment: @PM2Ring It seems like a valid channel, however the cross section would be astronomically small.